# jQuery SlideToggle Misehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of a conundrum...
I am using bootstrap on a wordpress site (locally) and I'm experiencing a weird effect in (what I thought would be) a simple slideToggle event. FYI, it only happens on mobile devices, and I am not using Bootstrap's js file - just css.

I have a list of LIs and inside a few is a UL with its respective LIs.

The nested UL has a display of none and when its parent LI is clicked an event is triggered - slideToggle.

On a regular desktop it works fine both on large display port and mobile emulators. but on any mobile device the slideToggle event only happens once. I click it opens, I click again it closes, I click again and nothing happens. BUT if I throw an alert inside the click event, the alert always fires even though the UL does not. I have tried different selectors, adding a stop propagation event and nothing seems to fix this.

Of course in my example below it is working fine. Also note that if I disable bootstrap's css, it then works fine on all platforms. but I don't see bootstrap adding any additional classes to the LIs or nested ULs.

```js
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click( function() {
      $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(350);
   });
```

```css
ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav opened-ul"><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8"><a title="Home" href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9 dropdown">
  <a title="Work" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Link 2 > <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
 <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41"><a title="Portfolio" href="#">Link Link 1</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a title="Case Studies" href="#">Link link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10"><a title="About" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11 dropdown"><a title="Rants" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Link 4 > <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a title="News" href="#">Link Link 3</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-42"><a title="Discoveries" href="#">Link Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a title="Contact" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a title="Search">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: You could try adding a class on click, and using `CSS` to animate the sliding. IMO CSS animations are often a bit more reliable than jQuery.

Comment: Yes I have gone down that route as well, and same behavior. It works first open/close, but no more after that.

Comment: So I narrowed down the issue to the css... Bootstrap sets the dropdown ULs as position:absolute. This is great when the main navigation is horizontal in large screens. For mobile, I'm overriding it to position:relative so i can slide the the following main nav LIs down, but since its position is now relative the slideToggle event only works one time - slides down, then slides up, no more sliding until i click refresh. why would the position affect the event? BTW if I omit the position:relative it works fine across all viewports, but if it is included only works on desktop viewports.

Comment: @Coleman At this point I just need it to function correctly, I can add effects later. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: hmmm... it's hard to say without actually having it in front of me, but it sounds like bootstrap is fighting you on some things. This is a big pet peeve of mine about bootstrap; its great until you get down to something small like this and then you have to fight it. But did you fix it by taking out the `position: relative`?

Comment: @Coleman Sorry for such a late reply.... but you hit the nail right in the head. Bootstrap was the issue...so annoying. I had to keep the dropdown UL as position absolute and live with it sitting on top on the LIs beneath it until I make a selection from the dropdown (or dropup in this case).

Comment: ah yeah, classic Bootstrap. FWIW when I'm looking for a small CSS library to help with grids and such, [this](http://getskeleton.com/) has been nice.